# Getting CERT_E_REVOCATION_FAILURE from WinVerifyTrust

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am developing a c# application, and using Pinvoke to call the method **[WinVerifyTrust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

the pinvoke declaration is as defined in [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust).

The RevocationChecks is set to none.

When trying to check my program on iExplorer, at first it worked ok and returned status ok for the file, but suddenly it started failing with CERT_E_REVOCATION_FAILURE, and then after a while it was ok again.

What might cause this weird behavior? does it mean that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: A little more info? Where did you get the certificate? Is it issued by a trusted root? Is it imported as trusted root? Who is returning the error at what point?

Comment: the winverify trust is getting a path, I just used the internet explorer's path.

Answer (score 1):

By default WinVerifyTrust tries to download any associated Certificate Revocation List (CRL) to verify that the certificate has not been explicitly revoked. If your connection to the Internet is not stable and the download fails, the CERT_E_REVOCATION_FAILURE is returned.

If you have some version of the Windows SDK installed, you can temporarily turn of the CRL download with the setreg tool. Keep in mind though that this should only be used temporarily to verify that the issues you are seeing are indeed related to CRL connectivity.

```
setreg.exe 3 FALSE
```

Documentation for the tool is available at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zaf80x7.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I don't have any issues with my internet connection but that might be the reason. but if I set RevocationChecks to none, why does it try to download CRL info?

Comment: Setting the RevocationChecks to None is not enough. See the SDK reference at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388205(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

Errors appearing and disappearing sound very much like a connection problem to the CRL or clock problems. However, the error message in clock related issues would be a different one - CERT_E_EXPIRED. The actual problem of CRL not being available is a very common one as most prod. environments have an unhindered access to the Internet. Usually the CRL checking is turned off for the whole environment in such cases.

Comment: I disconnected the internet, and the WinVerifyTrust returns status ok. why it doesn't fail with CERT_E_REVOCATION_FAILURE when the computer is not connected to the internet?

Comment: There is a cache in the CRLs, see the link in my previous comment.